# ¿Es "más y más" un anglicismo?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, diferencias-regionales, adverbios

Hay algunas expresiones del español de Hispanoamérica que a los hablantes de español europeo nos resultan curiosas. Para mí una de ellas es *[más y más](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWErHxJ#BhZf3F1)*. Pongo un ejemplo:

> Tengo más y más sueño.

Cuando en español europeo se diría:

> Cada vez tengo más sueño.

Siempre he tomado esta construcción *más y más* como un anglicismo, ya que *more and more* se define como *un número en aumento* o *incrementalmente*. Sin embargo, si algo he aprendido aquí es que no puedo dar nada por supuesto. Igual resulta que era una expresión común en España en el siglo XV y en América sencillamente ha perdurado mientras que en España no.

Así pues, ¿es el uso de *más y más* un anglicismo?

Comment: Según ngram ambas formas surgieron al mismo tiempo, pero cada vez más tuvo un crecimiento más extendido y el de más y más quedó estancando. Hoy en día cada vez más se usa casi 10 veces más frecuentemente que más y más

Comment: Charlie, creo que Mike hace un comentario válido en los comentarios de su respuesta. Sé que es práctica común hacer una "pregunta principal" e incluir algo de "bonus" o pregunta "adicional o tangencial" (Se usa esta expresión? Si sí es mucho o poco?/ Es esto un insulto en latinoamérica? Si sí en qué sitios? etc) Pero en este caso las "preguntas" adicionales pueden ser preguntas por peso propio. Si es un anglicismo y dónde se usa más son dos preguntas poco relacionadas, y quizá deberían ir en sus propios post para que la gente no responda a una y no la otra.

Comment: @Diego me parece bien, elimino las preguntas tangenciales y dejo la principal.

Comment: @guifa he reducido la pregunta para centrarla en el origen de la expresión, así que si quieres puedes cambiar tu comentario por una respuesta.

Comment: En México Cada vez mas me resulta la forma mas común y sencilla de usarlo

Mas y mas me parece más una expresión "torpe" y rara vez la he oído en una conversación

Comment: Según mi esposo (español y escritor) "más y más" se ha usado "de toda la vida", así que no está fuera de lo común. La RAE dice: ~ y ~.
1. loc. adv. Denota aumento continuado y progresivo. Como quería alcanzarlo, corrí más y más.

Comment: Sí, es un anglicismo, pero se ha empezado a oír entre los mexicanos.  // La respuesta de Mike deja claro, para mí, que él la considera un anglicismo.  Si se podría mejorar con un edit, pues sí se podría.  // Yo no quiero escribir una respuesta, creo que la de Mike se debe desborrar.

Comment: Si *más y más* es un anglicismo que entró a Hispanoamérica desde el norte, entonces no ha llegado a Argentina. Aquí decimos *cada vez más* exclusivamente, creo.

Comment: Si tu mismo dices que se usaba para la época del descubrimiento (siglo XV) es normal que haya llegado a América desde España y haya permanecido, así en España haya entrado en desuso. Para que fuera anglicismo tendría que haber desaparecido y luego reaparecer desde otro origen y no pienso que ese sea el caso.

Comment: In French we say the same "de plus en plus", and it's not an anglicism.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque en muchos casos el uso coloquial pueda estar influido por la expresión ***more and more*** en inglés —según algunas constataciones sobre personas en contacto angloparlante—, **estrictamente el término "*más y más*" registra antecedentes en el español antiguo**, al menos con un ejemplo de uso de 204 años atrás Tal es el   caso de [este documento](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=oRvNarmTwyQC&pg=PR5-IA11&dq=%22mas%20y%20mas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipuvLFzMnkAhWJF7kGHU1bCV44ChC7BQg0MAE#v=onepage&q=%22mas%20y%20mas%22&f=false) ***impreso en 1815 por la Real Academia Española conteníendolo.

De allí que se podría responder la pregunta diciendo **que no resulta  calificable  puramente como un anglicismo**

[image: glosario castellano de códigos antiguos]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an Anglicism.

Supporting evidence:

1. Unsophisticated people I encountered in Mexico did not say *más y más*, but they occasionally said *cada vez más*.
2. The only people I heard using "más y más" were people who used other Anglicisms in a sloppy way, in general, without consciously thinking about it.

Comment: Does sophisticated people use more anglicisms than unsophisticated people? I thought it was the opposite (No evidences, just an opinion)

Comment: @Ra_ - I guess it depends on where you are, and other factors.  I spent a lot of time in the countryside with no electricity and a visiting teacher with an irregular visiting schedule.  In the city, and also in the US, I've noticed that some well-educated people with some exposure to English were better than others at keeping the two languages separate.  I think it's not so much a measure of level of education as just the way the person's brain is wired.  Analogy: some bilingual children mix their languages like crazy until at least age three; others rarely mix, right from the start.

Comment: It's absolutely not evidences!!

Comment: @Quidam - I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying that my argument isn't convincing, because I didn't share any evidence?  En tu opinión, ¿“más y más” no es un anglicismo?

Comment: I just say that the supporting evidences are not evidences, I don't say that your opinion is wrong.

Comment: @Quidam - Thanks.  Are you saying that the argument I gave doesn't support my position?  Or maybe that it does a little bit, but it's not conclusive?  (Evidence is like water.  You have to have units of evidence to be able to make a plural.  For example, *pieces of evidence*.  But in general we can talk about *evidence*.  We just can't add an S.)

Comment: For me, it's not "proof", they prove nothing. But once again, I don't judge your conclusions, only the logics. You can use a weak proof, and come to a valid conclusion. But you can call it really a "proof" in this case, it's what I meant. For instance, your 1: unsophisticated people say this or that, is not linked with the fact it could be or not an anglicism.

Comment: @Quidam - Mi problema principal es que se me está dificultando entender bien bien lo que estás diciendo.  Tus expresiones en inglés tienen algunos errorcitos y eso me hace dudar de todas mis interpretaciones de lo que has escrito.  Te pido de favor que me lo expliques en el idioma que quieras, pero con un poco más cuidado.

Comment: English is not my native language, so it's normal that I use unnatural constructions. I'll write it in Spanish.

Comment: @Quidam - Noté tu observación arriba del francés.  También manejo el francés (no súper bien, pero creo que nos podríamos entender).  Fíjate que el comentario de Pablo (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26907/es-m%c3%a1s-y-m%c3%a1s-un-anglicismo/30302?noredirect=1#comment45010_26907) creo que apoya mi respuesta.